# Powershell command to update employee number from csv

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to write a powershell script that will update `employeeID` attribute in AD for each user

The script needs to update `employeeID` from my CSV file

Sample CSV:

```
user,employeeID
user1,1234567
```

Answer (score 1):

At least now you are trying some code which looks like it should work. Your logic is sound. Are you sure your CSV does not contain and blanks? Some simple statements could rule those out.

```
Import-CSV "C:\Scripts\Users.csv" | ForEach-Object { 
    $User = $_.UserName 
    $ID = $_.EmployeeID 
    If($user -and $ID){
        Set-ADUser $User -employeeID $ID 
    } Else {
        Write-Warning "User or employee number is null. Check source."
    }
```

The `If` statement would fail if either `$user` or `$id` was null. If that is not the case and your CSV does contain data maybe you are having an encoding issue.

Comment: well i receive User or employee number is null.

my csv file is
UserName,employeeID
user1,12345678

how can i upload a file ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on how you're finding the user in Active Directory... You could try something like this:

```
# import the users
$myUsers = Import-Csv csvFile.csv

# loop through each user and update their employeeID property
foreach ($user in $myUsers)
{
    # the Set-ADUser cmdlet requires a type of System.Hashtable<>,
    # so let's create one
    $updateRecord = @{"EmployeeID"=$user.EmployeeID}
    # Set the user attribute
    Set-ADUser -Identity $user -Replace @updateRecord
}
```

This might do the trick. Did you guys modify the AD Schema? Keep in mind that "EmployeeID" is assuming you have an EmployeeID Attribute on your Active Directory users.

Please let me know if it helps!